# Add RememberMe value as Claim in JWT (Identity Server 4)

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer 4.

Is it possible to access the value of the `RememberMe` boolean when issuing claims? (named `isPersistent` in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity)

My idea is to add a claim reflecting the `RememberMe` value so that other applications can use the value.

Currently I'm adding my Claims in the implementation of the interface `IProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync`.

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject).Result;
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                // I'm adding my current claims here, like so:
                new Claim("contact_id", user.ContactId.ToString()),
                // etc

                // I would like to add RememberMe
                new Claim("remember_me", ??? )
            };
            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
 // ..
```

Or can the `RememberMe` value be accessed by some other method?

Comment: Just add the value as a claim on login.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional claims during the user's login. There is an overload for **SignInAsync** which accepts an array of additional claims. 
Here is a code snippet.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
...
                AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                Claim keepMeLoggedIn = null;
                if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                {
                    props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                    };
                    keepMeLoggedIn = new Claim(AccountOptions.KeepLoggedInClaim, true.ToString());

                }

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userId.ToString(), model.Username, props, keepMeLoggedIn);
```

Please note that to make this solution work it's necessary to insert your claim name to the **IdentityClaims** table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you should add claim to tokens . In standard OIDC specifications, token is the
 bond between client and identity provider .  The profile service is called whenever IdentityServer needs to return claims about a user to a client applications , and could be used to add your custom claims .

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html

Comment: He is asking for how to access the value of the RememberMe when issuing claims.
BTW I am also looking for same.